# Handling Large Form with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a large registration form in a React-redux page.

I do not need to bind any data to the forms, as it will always load blank, and on submit can just send data to API and be redirected to a "Please check our email" page.

The issue I am also having, is that I am using MaterializeReact and using their custom  Components. This just renders as a input with a name, so traditional formdata would be intact..

All the examples online, seem to want me to create a state, then for each input element I bind the state to it, and then all my values will be in this.state.

It seems a little bit of a long way around, as I have 30, 40 fields.

I found a way using refs, but I did no want to use it as I know ref strings are being deprecated. The ref solution is like so:

```
submitform() {
    const formData = {};
    for (const field in this.refs) {
      formData[field] = this.refs[field].value;
    }
    //Now I have the all values wrapped in a object to send to server
  }

<form>
  <Input ref="firstName" />  //MaterializeReact Component. Renders as <input>
 <button type="button" onclick="{submitForm}" />
</form>
```

What would be the recommend way of getting the value of many inputs without the hassle of binding each one?

Comment: Have look into this demo of 5000 form fields without any performance lag: https://hookstate.netlify.com/performance-demo-large-form It uses state hook to bind form fields, but it is the way to go in React. Disclaimer: I am an author of the project.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two recommended ways to handle forms by the react team are controlled and uncontrolled components. Creating and maintaining a state is no more round-about than using a uncontrolled components like your initial suggestion with `refs` where you built your own state called `formData` before submitting the data.

Here's the equivalent solution using state, and it won't be deprecated.

```
submitform() {
    const formData = this.state
    //Now I have the all values wrapped in a object to send to server
}

handleOnChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target
    this.setState({ [name] : value })
}

<form>
    <Input name="firstName" onChange={this.handleOnChange} /> //MaterializeReact Component. Renders as <input>
    <button type="button" onclick="{submitForm}" />
</form>
```

Comment: can we do the same in functional components ? i mean , is it ok to use too many `useState` to store value of each input and then pack them into a single object while submitting ?

Comment: @BrightFaith If I understand correctly, having each input store its own value, then collecting all the values onSubmit can work. All it does is make the method of submit slower because it will now need to iterate over N-many inputs to collect/pack their data. The memory limit of one state object versus many state objects are the same - which is the limit of memory in your browser. Ultimately, it is okay but seems like an unnecessary complexity for this particular example. In most simple apps this decision shouldn't effect speed much if at all.

Answer (score 6):

While working with large forms there are some challenges which you may face:

- **Performance Issues**

You're components must be designed in a way that the changes in one input should not affect the other until it's required.

- **Scalabilty**

It should be easy to add & remove form controls.

- **State Management**

It's not easy to maintain a centralized state with all controls information like touched, error etc.

- **Dynamic Changes**

For example: Disable a field based on the value of other field.

- **Validations & Errors**
- **Nested Forms**

So, it's better to save effort & time by using some form library.

Checkout this library [react-reactive-form](https://github.com/bietkul/react-reactive-form)

Some of the cool features are:

- UI independent.
- Zero dependencies.
- Nested forms.
- Subscribers for value & status changes of controls.
- Provides a set of validators & also supports custom sync & async validators.
- FormGenerator api to create large forms with less code.
- Better form management with FormGroup & FormArray apis.
- Customizable update strategy for better performace with large forms.

Comment: Kuldeep, is this library still actively maintained? Didn't see many changes in past few months.